# System Service callbacks and the main thread's event loop

Tags: android

I was wondering what is really happening when I register a callback object with a system service. In my case I register a BluetoothGattCallback when connecting to a BLE device. I discovered that the callback is not happening on the main thread of my application when I tried to update a TextView within one of my callback methods.

My understanding is that lifecycle and other methods called by the framework are somehow (possibly through an ipc handler in Application) added to my main thread Looper's MessageQueue (event loop) and get executed on my main thread when the Looper ticks that particular message in its iteration loop.

So what is really going on when my GATT callback methods are called? When they run on a different thread does that impose concurrency? Is there some synchronization mechanism involved? Is the main thread's event loop bypassed? Or do I have a complete misunderstanding of the underlying concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple threads running in the virtual machine. All of the Android lifecycle methods run on the main (UI) thread and a lot of system callbacks also run on the main thread. However, some callbacks will run on other threads, either because you ask for this behaviour or because the callbacks are programmed like that.

Since the callbacks you mention are running on other threads (not the main (UI) thread), you must make sure that you don't do anything with the UI within the code that executes in the callback methods. You can easily get around this issue by wrapping anything you do in a `Runnable` and run that on the main (UI) thread by calling `runOnUiThread()`.

Regarding concurrency, that depends on your application architecture. If the code that runs in the callback methods is accessing data that you also access in code running on the main (UI) thread, then you have concurrent access to that data and you need to provide any necessary synchronization (if necessary) to avoid problems.

You ask about the main thread's event loop. If these callbacks are not running on the main (UI) thread, then they don't have anything to do with the main thead and it's event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. Up to now I thought that an app by default lives in a process with just one thread. I found [this clarification](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/XYBZ1d_Lovg/zbi1HKJPA3MJ) by Dianne Hackborn on a Google Group:

> Specifically, each process has a pool of "binder threads" which sit there waiting for incoming IPCs from other process.  When an IPC is dispatched to your process, one of these threads comes out of the pool to process it.  These may come to you directly through an IBinder you publish from a Service to another process, semi-directly through calls from another process to a ContentProvider you have published, or indirectly from a wide range of IPCs the system does into app processes to tell it to launch an activity, receive an intent, etc.
>
> Dianne Hackborn
>   Android framework engineer